How to convert dataframes to arrays in a for loop
I have imported data from multiple csv files, creating multiple data frames. I need to use a for loop for the rest of my code and for that code, I need the data frames to be in an array.
I have tried putting all the data frames in a list with the idea that the loop can perform its tasks for one data set at a time.
This is essentially what I have at the moment.
data_sets=[data1,data2,data3]
for x in data_sets:
   y=data[x].to_numpy()

I keep getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Why not y=x.to_numpy() ?

x is not an index into the List; it is the DF object. Use y=x.to_numpy()

data isn't defined here. In the future, please make a [mre], which can help catch basic mistakes like this. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips.

Try this. I believe it is simply typo on your end.
data_sets = [data1, data2, data3]

for df in data_sets:
    y = df.to_numpy()


Firstly u need to convert df to numpy by using df.to_numpy(). After that, u can add your df into array. In your code data[x] means nothing. Your x is df which came from your data_sets. So, instead  of that u need to use x.to_numpy
for df in data_sets:
    array = df.to_numpy()
    arrays.append(array)

Then print numpy arrays.
for i, array in enumerate(arrays):
    print(f"Array {i+1}:")
    print(array)
    print()


You are getting a type error because you used 'x' as an index but in your iteration 'x' is actually represents each element (dataframe) when you iterate through the list.If you want to use index then you need to use range to iterate though the list.
data_sets=[data1,data2,data3]

for x in range(len(data_sets)):
    y=data_sets[x].to_numpy()
    print(y)

